# Gmail Sign In Problem in my Android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

It is allowing me to login through Gmail and its showing display picture, my name etc. but its not working with other random people's id.

I've added more owners on developer.google.com and its also allowing them but not me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private LinearLayout Prof_Section;
    private Button SignOut;
    private SignInButton  SignIn;
    private TextView Name,Email;
    private ImageView Prof_Pic;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private static final int REQ_CODE=9001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Prof_Section = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Prof_Section);
        SignOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_logout);
        SignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.bn_login);
        Name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        Prof_Pic=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);
        SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,signInOptions).build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.bn_login:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.bn_logout:
                signOut();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    private void signIn()
    {
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
    }
    private void signOut()
    {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                updateUI(false);
            }
        });

    }
    private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {if(result.isSuccess())
    {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email = account.getEmail();
        String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Name.setText(name);
        Email.setText(email);
       // Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
      //  Glide.with(this)
             //   .load(img_url)
           // //    .override(300, 200)
             //   .into(Prof_Pic);
      //  Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_pic);
        updateUI(true);

    }
    else
    {updateUI(false);}

    }
    private void updateUI(boolean isLogin){
        if(isLogin){
            Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SignIn.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        }
        else
        {
            Prof_Section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(requestCode==REQ_CODE)
        {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleResult(result);
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Prof_Section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="176dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prof_pic"
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/myalpha"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Name display here"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Email display here"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bn_logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:text="Logout Google Account" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/bn_login"
        >

    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its logging me and showing me my details but not others people details.
I want that if they try to login, they also get there details

Answer (score 0):

SignInButton Signin = findViewById(R.id.);

findViewById(R.id.bn_login).setOnClickListener(this);

findViewById(R.id.bn_login).setVisibility(View.GONE);